# How do I find out which text field is responding to Textfielddidend

Tags: objective-c

I have multiple uitextfields but they all respond to the delegate the method. I tried using textfield description but that doesn't work. There must be a way to know which text field is active but I can't find it.
thanks.

Comment: What is the exact problem? The delegate method sends the corresponding text field: - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [`UITextFieldDelegate` protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html), all the methods pass the UITextField that's calling the method. For example:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

You can just check the text field against a known one:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.fooBarField)
    {
       //do magic
    }
    return YES;
}
```